# Finding the moment generating function of $\min(Y,1)$

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, exponential-distribution

Let $Y\sim\text{Exp}(1)$ be a random variable. I denote the random variable $X$ as $X=\min(Y,1)$. The task is to find the moment generating function of $X$.

By simply calculating the probability I managed to find the CDF of $X$ is:
$$F_X(t) = \begin{cases}
1-e^{-t},  & 0 \le t <1\\
1, & t \ge 1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Here I got stuck. Since $X$ is not a continuous variable, it does not have a PDF, and without it I do not know how to calculate the moment generating function. ($X$ is also not discrete).

I will appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

The  definition of the moment generating function does not require a PDF.
$$\phi_X(t) := E[e^{tX}].$$

From here, it may be helpful to write
$$e^{tX} = e^{tX} \mathbf{1}\{Y > 1\} + e^{tX} \mathbf{1}\{Y \le 1\}$$
and compute the expectation of the two terms separately.

---

Edit for more details:

$$E[e^{tX} \mathbf{1}\{Y > 1\}] = E[e^{tY} \mathbf{1}\{Y > 1\}] = \int_1^\infty e^{ty} f_Y(y) \, dy = \cdots.$$
$$E[e^{tX} \mathbf{1}\{Y \le 1\}] = e^t E[\mathbf{1}\{Y \le 1\}] = e^t P(Y \le 1) = \cdots.$$

Comment: Could you show me how?

Comment: Thank you! But I think the integral needs to be from 0 to 1

Comment: Thank you! But I think the integral needs to be from 0 to 1